# ClientHelper: CmisConnectionException: Cannot initalize Web Services service object

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, cmis, opencmis

At login to my CMIS-enabled SharePoint 2013 Standard at `http://192.168.0.20/_vti_bin/cmissoapwsdl.aspx` as Web Service, [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) says:

```
ClientHelper: CmisConnectionException: Cannot initalize Web Services service object
```

[Here is the response of the endpoint (pastebin because StackOverflow is limited to 30k characters)](http://pastebin.com/vNFDnp4e), it looks OK to me, so what is the problem?

```
Full CMIS Workbench log:
> 16:59:01 DEBUG dings.spi.webservices.CmisWebServicesSpi: Initializing Web Services SPI...
> 16:59:01 DEBUG ngs.spi.webservices.AbstractPortProvider: Initializing Web Service org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.webservices.RepositoryService...
> 16:59:01 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: CmisConnectionException: Cannot initalize Web Services service object [org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.webservices.RepositoryService]: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Cannot initalize Web Services service object [org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.binding.webservices.RepositoryService]: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.AbstractPortProvider.initServiceObject(AbstractPortProvider.java:288)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.AbstractPortProvider.getPortObject(AbstractPortProvider.java:206)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.AbstractPortProvider.getRepositoryServicePort(AbstractPortProvider.java:109)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.model.ClientSession.connect(ClientSession.java:186)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.model.ClientSession.<init>(ClientSession.java:105)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.LoginDialog.createClientSession(LoginDialog.java:547)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.LoginDialog$1.actionPerformed(LoginDialog.java:154)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
> 16:59:01 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: Error code: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an authentication problem. Try downloding the WSDL with a web browser to your local disk and then use a file:// URL to refer to it in the Workbench.

If that works, check the authentication configuration on the SharePoint side. OpenCMIS cannot handle protected WSDLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found the issue that causes this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-294